# Attachment option customization in data form webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, attachments, data-form-web-part, out-of-the-box

We have requirement that Implement attachment control same (Like InfoPath form screen shot) as it is in the default form of new item. Please let me know if any one have solution / workaround.

1) InfoPath form screen shot.
[image]

2) SP Default New item form screen shot.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution on following link.

http://vishalmarnepune.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-add-attach-file-control-on.html